# MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit Dialog Boxes do not closed by pressing the ENTER key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dialog, material-design-in-xaml

I am using MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit for WPF. I am trying to close Dialogs by pressing the ENTIRE key.

Here is my DialogHost:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="dialog_CONNECT"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
                            <StackPanel Margin="16">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_CONNECTED_DIALOG" />
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                                            **IsDefault="True"**
                                            Margin="0 8 8 0"
                                            Content="OK"
                                            Command="materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>

                        <Button x:Name="button_CONNECT" Content="CONNECT"
                                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}"  
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                IsDefault="True"
                                Margin="8 0 0 0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Click="onClickConnect"/>

                    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

In the code-behind I provide to open the dialog when I click on *button_CONNECT* (setting dialog_CONNECT.IsOpen = true).

Why if I now press the ENTIRE key the dialog box does not close?

Comment: There is a current issue where the dialog button may not get enabled properly, until you click into the dialog.  Is the button greyed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a TextBox into the DialogContent to fix it, but I do not know if it also a workaround.

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="dialog_CONNECT"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
                        <StackPanel Margin="16">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_CONNECTED_DIALOG" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                                **<TextBox /> <!-- To allow IsDefault property on following button -->**
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                                        IsDefault="True"
                                        Margin="0 8 8 0"
                                        Content="OK"
                                        Command="materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>

                    <Button x:Name="button_CONNECT" Content="CONNECT"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}"  
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            IsDefault="True"
                            Margin="8 0 0 0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Click="onClickConnect"/>

                </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```